# Google Spreadsheets: Sum over multiple criteria constrained by timeframe

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Hello Everyone (this is all in Google Spreadsheets),

I'm trying to make a report where I have to sum the product of the number of Apples and Bananas bought respectively within a certain time frame by different people. The price of the goods differs, depending on who is buying them. The people who buy it do so at different times and purchase a different number of items. The formula should be extendable to include additional people in the future.

For details see this [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11-B2z9eeGwa88yhY5EnWx0adMekfTuc__E7tc_ofOCM/edit?usp=sharing).

I would like to get the calculation *without* needing steps in-between. If it makes any difference, the number of items bought on specific dates are actually in different worksheets, so they're not on the same page as in the example. I named the ranges accordingly (even though I believe/hope it makes little difference in terms of what formula to use).
Finally, if it were possible to use one formula for the total expenditures, instead of the sum over the cells above that would be grand.

I use the DATEVALUE, because otherwise I wouldn't be able to find the first and the last date of the calendar weeks. There is a dedicated DATEVALUE column in every worksheet. (Additionally, I don't have to deal with the intricacies of the date format, which gets me every time.)

I hope I didn't miss an answer to my problem and provided enough information. I can't get my head around it, I am really looking forward to your answers.

Thank you everyone :)
Greg

P.S. A picture of the sheet, if required: [Apples, Bananas & €](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5RRj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Sennsei from the Google Docs Help Forum ([Link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/72CG4o9fI1g;context-place=mydiscussions)). I quote:

I won't be surprised if this isn't the best way to go about this, but regardless, here's my take on solving your problem. Result is based on [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Utrbr2Db6wURUJe2iGoufG0JcijvxP6A1mHpJvSQ4WE/edit#gid=643073624) modified worksheet.

Apples:
=IFERROR(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(FILTER('Prices/Amounts'!$J$4:$J,'Prices/Amounts'!$K$4:$K>=B4,'Prices/Amounts'!$K$4:$K<=B5),FILTER('Prices/Amounts'!$J$4:$L,'Prices/Amounts'!$K$4:$K>=B4,'Prices/Amounts'!$K$4:$K<=B5),3,0))*ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(FILTER('Prices/Amounts'!$J$4:$J,'Prices/Amounts'!$K$4:$K>=B4,'Prices/Amounts'!$K$4:$K<=B5), 'Prices/Amounts'!$B$3:$D,3,0)))),0)

Bananas:
=IFERROR(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(FILTER('Prices/Amounts'!$F$4:$F,'Prices/Amounts'!$G$4:$G>=B4,'Prices/Amounts'!$G$4:$G<=B5),FILTER('Prices/Amounts'!$F$4:$H,'Prices/Amounts'!$G$4:$G>=B4,'Prices/Amounts'!$G$4:$G<=B5),3,0))*ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(FILTER('Prices/Amounts'!$F$4:$F,'Prices/Amounts'!$G$4:$G>=B4,'Prices/Amounts'!$G$4:$G<=B5), 'Prices/Amounts'!$B$3:$D,2,0)))),0)

Expenditure:
=B7+B8

The B4's and B5's refer to the date constraints. Since the formulae contain $ signs to ensure the cells stay the same, the formula can be dragged across to apply to other weeks without having to touch the formulae. As a plus side, these formulae allows a sheet to be infinitely expandable!

Sennsei